# C# Функция запрос-ответ в System.IO.Ports.SerialPort

Tags: c#, .net, serial

Здравствуйте, есть функция которая отправляет в послед порт N байт, и ожидает получение ответа (N байт ответа) заданное время, если данные получены быстрее то остаток времени не ждем а переходим к след. запросу, если за заданное время данные не получены, то считаем что ответа нет.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Функция посылает запрос в порт, и как только в буфер порта приходят данные сразу же проверяет их кол-во.
    /// Как только накопится нужное кол-во байт сразу же будет возвращен ответ не дожедаясь времени readTimeout.
    /// Таким образом период опроса не фиксированный, а определяется скоростью ответа slave устройства.
    /// </summary>
    public async Task<byte[]> RequestAndRespawnInstantlyAsync(byte[] writeBuffer, int nBytesRead, int readTimeout, CancellationToken ct)
    {
        if (!_port.IsOpen)
            return null;

        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<byte[]>();
        SerialDataReceivedEventHandler handler = null;
        try
        {
            //очистили буферы порта
            _port.DiscardInBuffer();
            _port.DiscardOutBuffer();

            //_port.WriteTimeout = 500; //??????
            _port.Write(writeBuffer, 0, writeBuffer.Length);     //отправили данные в порт

            //ждем ответа....
            handler = (o, e) =>
            {
                if (_port.BytesToRead >= nBytesRead)
                {
                    var buffer = new byte[nBytesRead];
                    _port.Read(buffer, 0, nBytesRead);
                    tcs.TrySetResult(buffer);
                }
            };
            _port.DataReceived += handler;

            var buff = await AsyncHelp.WithTimeout(tcs.Task, readTimeout, ct);
            return buff;
        }
        catch (TimeoutException)
        {
            tcs.TrySetCanceled();
            throw;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            StatusString = $"Ошибка работы с портом (DataExchangeAsync): {_port.PortName}. ОШИБКА: {ex}  InnerException: {ex.InnerException?.Message ?? string.Empty}";
            ReOpen();
            return null;
        }
        finally
        {
            _port.DataReceived -= handler;
        }
    }
```

Я написал класс MasterSerialPort в котром есть очередь выполняющихся по циклу функций запрос-ответов.
код работает в боевом режиме уже достаточно давно, но проанализировав логи я примерно раза 3 в сутки замечаю InvalidOperationException на методе `_port.Write(writeBuffer, 0, writeBuffer.Length);`
Этот Exception возникает, если на закрытом порту выполняются действия, но как закрывается порт во время работы я не могу понять. Аппаратная это ошибка или функция обмена написана криво у меня?

Comment: А вы случайно не вызываете несколько RequestAndRespawnInstantlyAsync одновременно?

Comment: Вы имеете в виду 2 экземпляра моего класса MasterSerialPort, в которых параллельно вызываются RequestAndRespawnInstantlyAsync? Т.е. 2 параллельно работающих порта?

Comment: Нет, один параллельно работающий. Так точно не бывает?

Comment: Думаю нет, вручную эта функция вызваться не может, она вызывается внутри цикла, где последовательно вызываются данные функции, внутри которых уже вызывается RequestAndRespawnInstantlyAsync.

Comment: Попытаюсь в лог отловить попытку одновременного использования.